# How to fetch records in pages in Android

Tags: sql, android, database, sqlite, mobility

I want to use the SQLite clause **LIMIT** and **OFFSET**, so that I can fetch my records in pages.
But, though I can find the **LIMIT** clause in the *SQLiteQueryBuilder.query()* which would effectively limit the number of record in my result. 
Couldn't find the **OFFSET** clause anywhere so that I can continue fetching from the point I left.
Also, can someone explain to me the exact use of *SelectionArgs[]* in the query() function, with some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just give the Limit and Offset parameters in the where clause , in this way

```
tmpCol.query(Tablename, columns, "WHERE Clause LIMIT xx OFFSET yy",
                                selectionArgs[], having, orderBy);
```

Comment: I don't think you should put a "WHERE" in the where clause. The API does it foryou.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
db.query(TABLENAME, 
  new String[] { _ID,NAME,CHILDREN },
  NAME+"=? OR "+CHILDREN+" > ? ", 
  new String[] { "John","3"},
  null, 
  null, 
  " 25 OFFSET 100"); //or 100, 25
```

Please note everything is string, so the where clause replacements must also be strings